# Let $A$ be the set of factors of $36$ and $B$ be the set of multiples of $3$. List down the elements of the following:

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A$ be the set of all factors of $36$ and $B$ be the set of multiples of $3$.  List down the elements of the following:

$A = \{1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36\}$

$B = \{3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,36,\dots\}$

1. $A\cap B$
2. $A\setminus B$

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Both of these will be contained in $A$, which is finite -- can you list the elements of $A$?

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you looked at the definitions of the symbols?  Have you listed $A$ and $B$?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner I already listed them.

Comment: Good job.  Now you are one step closer to a solution.  (You listed only those elements of $B$ between $1$ and $36$, but that won't matter.)  Do you understand what $A\cap B$ means?

Comment: This question is just making sure you understand symbols and terminology.  What elements in $A$ are also in $B$?  What elements of $A$ are not in $B$?

Comment: As an aside, don't use the [education] tag.  That is meant for questions about the pedagogy of teaching such as "how frequently should students take tests to make sure they're on the right track" or similar... The tag is not to be used just because you are studying in a school.

Comment: @J.W.Tanner sort of but here is my answer {3,6,9,12,18,36}, can you check it for me?

Comment: Yes, $\{3,6,9,12,18,36\}$ is indeed the set of divisors of $36$ who are also multiples of $3$.  Be confident.

Comment: @JMoravitz a. ∩ - {3,6,9,12,18,36} b. \ - {1,2,4}? Is this correct also

Comment: Yes, @bdlCookies, both of your answers are correct

Comment: @J.W.Tanner a. ∩ - {3,6,9,12,18,36} b. \ - {1,2,4}. Is this correct also?

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x\in A\cap B\iff x\in A\text{ and } x\in b$. So $A\cap B$ is the set of elements who belong to both sets.

On the other hand $x\in A\setminus B\iff x\in A \text{ and } x\notin B$. So $A\setminus B$ is the set of all elements of $A$ which are not a member of $B$.

You can now use this to conclude.

Answer (score 0):

By the given information about the sets $A$ and $B$, we have :

- $A=  \{1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36\}$
- $B = \{3,6,9,12,15,18,21,24,27,30,36,…\}$

since $A$ is the set of factors of $36$ and $B$ is the set of multiples of $3$.

---

**SOLUTION - 1:-**

Now, recall the definition of intersection of two sets. Intersection of two sets say set $A$ and $B$, denoted by $A\cap B$ is the set of all those elements which belong to both the sets $A$ as well as $B$.

Therefore, $A\cap B = \{3,6,9,12,18,36\}$.

---

**SOLUTION - 2 :-**

Now, we have to find $A$ \ $B$.

$A$ \ $B$ is the set of all those elements which belongs to A but don't belong to the set $B$.

So, clearly $A$ \ $B$ =  $\{1,2,4\}$

---

Additionally you may learn about difference of sets from [here](https://www.thoughtco.com/difference-of-two-sets-3126580) and about intersection of two sets from [here](https://www.cuemath.com/algebra/intersection-of-sets/)